# Не правильно выполняется условие в python 2

Tags: python, django, python-2.x, if

Есть следующий код:

```
items = 99
page_id = 1
num_page = 2

if page_id <= num_page:
    items = 1
else:
    items = 0

print(items) # 1
```

Теперь возьмем следующий код:

```
print(page_id, paginator.num_pages) # (1, 2)
if page_id <= paginator.num_pages:
    items = paginator.page(page_id)
else:
    items = None

print(items) # None
```

В чем проблема?

Оказалось, что `page_id = u'1'` во втором случае:

```
print(page_id, paginator.num_pages, page_id <= paginator.num_pages)
# (u'1', 2, False)
```

Comment: @andreymal, попробовал, ответ все равно None

Comment: @andreymal, можно даже заменить None на 99, вернет 99. Версия о том, что paginator.page(page_id) возвращает None отсекается

Comment: Не воспроизводится, оба кода работают как положено https://i.imgur.com/C1zYeZ7.png

Comment: @andreymal в консоли тоже не воспроизводится.

Comment: Значит вопрос подлежит закрытию, пока вы не дадите такой код, проблема в котором воспроизводится ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @andreymal, все понятно :) `print(page_id, paginator.num_pages, page_id <= paginator.num_pages) # (u'1', 2, False)`

Comment: Ну вот, вы в коде из вопроса наврали) Строка всегда больше числа, да

Comment: связанный вопрос [How does Python compare string and int?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3270680/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При сравнении разных типов, для которых явно не определено [сравнение в Питоне 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons):

> Objects of different types, except different numeric types and different string types, never compare equal; such objects are ordered consistently but arbitrarily (so that sorting a heterogeneous array yields a consistent result)

Используется порядок зависящий от реализации. На CPython 2:

> Objects of different types except numbers are ordered by their type names;

Поэтому `u'1' <= 2` равнозначно: `'unicode' <= 'int'`, что всегда `False`.

В Питоне 3 это ошибка:

```
>>> '1' <= 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: str() <= int()
```